# How can I write a WAV file from byte array in Java

Tags: java

I'd like to develop a simple java music player to accelerate and play music using this Sonic Algorithm [github/Sonic.java](https://github.com/waywardgeek/sonic/blob/master/Sonic.java). And here's the main class: [github/Main.java](https://github.com/waywardgeek/sonic/blob/master/Main.java). The Main.java simply calls Sonic.java and then it can play the music. Even though it works well when running a WAV file, but what I want is to write a new WAV file from the accelerated input stream.

I've tried to write bytes to a ByteArrayOutputStream in the do-while loop of Main.java, and transformed them into a local WAV file, while the generated music gets cut off and obviously there have some lost data during this process.

```
public class App {

private static void runSonic(
        AudioInputStream audioStream,
        SourceDataLine line,
        float speed,
        float pitch,
        float rate,
        float volume,
        boolean emulateChordPitch,
        int quality,
        int sampleRate,
        int numChannels) throws IOException
{
    Sonic sonic = new Sonic(sampleRate, numChannels);
    int bufferSize = line.getBufferSize();
    byte inBuffer[] = new byte[bufferSize];
    byte outBuffer[] = new byte[bufferSize];
    int numRead,numWritten;
    AudioFormat af = audioStream.getFormat();
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    sonic.setSpeed(speed);
    sonic.setPitch(pitch);
    sonic.setRate(rate);
    sonic.setVolume(volume);
    sonic.setChordPitch(emulateChordPitch);
    sonic.setQuality(quality);
    int count = 0;
    do {
        numRead = audioStream.read(inBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
        if(numRead <= 0) {
            sonic.flushStream();
        } else {
            sonic.writeBytesToStream(inBuffer, numRead);
        }
        do {
            numWritten = sonic.readBytesFromStream(outBuffer, bufferSize);
            if(numWritten > 0) {
                line.write(outBuffer, 0, numWritten);
                output.write(outBuffer);
            }
        } while(numWritten > 0);
    } while(numRead > 0);


    byte fileBuffer[] = output.toByteArray();

    ByteArrayInputStream bais1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileBuffer);

    AudioInputStream aisAccelerated1 =
            new AudioInputStream(bais1, af, fileBuffer.length);
    try {
        AudioSystem.write(aisAccelerated1, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, new
                File("newFile.wav")
        );
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(
        String[] argv) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException, LineUnavailableException
{
    float speed = 1.5f;
    float pitch = 1.5f;
    float rate = 1.0f;
    float volume = 1.0f;
    boolean emulateChordPitch = false;
    int quality = 0;
    String fileName = "file.wav";

    AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(fileName));
    AudioFormat format = stream.getFormat();
    int sampleRate = (int)format.getSampleRate();
    int numChannels = format.getChannels();
    SourceDataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format,
            ((int)stream.getFrameLength()*format.getFrameSize()));
    SourceDataLine line = (SourceDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    line.open(stream.getFormat());
    line.start();
    runSonic(stream, line, speed, pitch, rate, volume, emulateChordPitch, quality,
            sampleRate, numChannels);
    line.drain();
    line.stop();
}
```

}

Who can tell me what's going on here? I think all bytes stored in outBuffer has been writted into the output stream in this way.

You can find the whole class using the links above.

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in the question, not via links. If it's too much code, try to narrow it down. This might help: [MCVE]

Comment: Thank you, it plays well now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
output.write(outBuffer);
```

The problem is here. It should be

```
output.write(outBuffer, 0, numWritten);
```

You are writing garbage to the output.